# How to keep Intellij commit changelist from disappearing?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, changelist

I created a changelist called local which stores all the local set up that shouldn't be committed. However, it keeps disappearing. Sometimes if disappears after a commit, or I open intellij the next day and the lists are gone and only 'changes' list is there.

In my settings I already set 'when anempty changelist becomes inactive' to 'Do nothing'. Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What does git status return in the CMD? Does it show changes from the changelist?

Is the changelist inactive when it disappears? Can you also check if your changelist is shelved in shelf?

Does this always happen? Any exact reproduction steps?

Also, it's best to contact support with logs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files